# Javascript's performance.now() and Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, performance.now

I'm new to Nodejs and I'm confused about something when timing:

If Nodejs is Javascript, then why Javascript's performance.now() doesn't work on Nodejs and I'm forced to use console.time() or the like?

How can I know what other Javascript functions doesn't work on Node?

Thanks!

Comment: The `performance` API is a web browser thing; it's not part of JavaScript proper, just like the DOM is not part of JavaScript.

Comment: In Node, you probably want `process.hrtime()`. Anyhow, some API's are host-specific. Best way to know for sure is test.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Update: Although this was correct at the time it was written, this answer is now obsolete and modern versions of Node do support `performance.now()`**

First, we have to be very clear about what JavaScript does -- and does not include.

The definition for what JavaScript includes is the [EMCA-262 guide](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/).  This is the only thing that JavaScript is required to have.

Everything else - from the `DOM` to the `performance` object are additions provided by the host environment.

Some -- many -- browsers have chosen to add `performance.now()` but that is NOT part of JavaScript -- just something that JavaScript can call.

`nodeJS` currently doesn't support it -- at least not out-of-the-box, but it looks like someone created a module that does give you that ability.

I've not tried it, just did a quick google for 'node performance.now` and this was the first hit:  https://www.npmjs.com/package/performance-now

Comment: Node v8.5.0 has added [Performance Timing API](https://nodejs.org/api/perf_hooks.html#perf_hooks_performance_timing_api), which includes the [`performance#now()`](https://nodejs.org/api/perf_hooks.html#perf_hooks_performance_now).

Comment: `import {
  performance
} from 'perf_hooks'` Worked great in 11